# Pandas - Find values between dataframes and add values of a series for the matched

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search for the values of DataframeB.ColA in DataframeA.IDCol2 and then create a dataframe with the DataframeA.IDCol1 and the sum of DataframeA.IDCol3 for the values that were matched.

DataframeA

```
        IDCol1      IDCol2      IDCol3
0       ABC         123         2
1       ABC         456         5
2       ABC         789         2
3       ABC         1011        1
4       CDE         123         3
5       CDE         456         2
6       CDE         CCC         4
7       CDE         AAA         1
```

DataframeB

```
        ColA        
0       123     
1       456     
2       CCC     
3       1011
```

Output

```
        Col     Sum     
0       ABC     8       
1       CDE     9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`series.isin()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=series+isin&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=series+isin&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2462j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and `groupby()` with `sum`:

```
dfA[dfA.IDCol2.isin(dfB.ColA)].groupby('IDCol1')['IDCol3'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum')
```

---

```
  IDCol1  Sum
0    ABC    8
1    CDE    9
```

Comment: All acceptable and beautiful answers but I can only "accept" one, so I am going to with yours because it's one line and so elegant. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) first and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = (DataframeA.merge(DataframeB, left_on='IDCol2', right_on='ColA')
                .groupby('IDCol1', as_index=False)['IDCol3']
                .sum())
print (df)
  IDCol1  IDCol3
0    ABC       8
1    CDE       9
```

Another solution:

```
s = DataframeB['ColA']
df = DataframeA.set_index('IDCol1').query('IDCol2 in @s')['IDCol3'].sum(level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  IDCol1  IDCol3
0    ABC       8
1    CDE       9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `IDCol1` and aggregate with the `sum`:

```
(DataframeA.merge(DataframeB, left_on='IDCol2', right_on='ColA')
           .groupby('IDCol1')
           .IDCol3.sum()
           .reset_index())

   IDCol1  IDCol3
0    ABC       8
1    CDE       9
```